# Array Notation Order of Operations

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written the following code

```
o[s += "a"] = o[s += "b"] = o[s += "c"] = 0;
```

I was curious as to why the variable `s` ends up storing "abc" and not "cba". It seems like it would be easier for the the code to execute from right to left.

I seems as though the executor chooses and index for storage then decides what goes in there, but doing this make it sound slower since there would be so many states and memory being pushed onto the stack. Can somebody explain as to why it makes sense for the code to execute in the order that is does?

I have included a fiddle with a few more examples. http://jsfiddle.net/eggrdtuk/3/

Comment: I believe that the statements between [], (like when using `()`) will be executed first, in the order as the parser sees it. so at the end you have `o["a"] = o["ab"] = o["abc"] = 0;` which then will be executed from right to left.

Comment: I'm not sure how executing it right-to-left rather than left-to-right would make sense. The indexes must be calculated first before it can do any assignments.

Comment: @MattBurland i was thinking it would start from the right, determine what is about to be stored, then where, not the other way around...i would think there is considerable savings in both time and space complexity

Comment: @LoganMurphy: I still don't buy that would make sense. Nor do I buy that there really is any savings in time and space to be made here. It's not a common construction to start with and if it really was an issue then it's something a javascript engine could likely be optimized for.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luke's comment is right. We can look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for operator precedence.

Computed Member Access has precedence 1 and Assignment has precedence 16. So the property access expressions are evaluated first, then the assignment operations. Furthermore, Computed Member Access has left-to-right associativity, while Assignment has right-to-left associativity.

So, we can think of the first step as parsing the property access expressions from left-to-right:

```
 o["a"] = o["ab"] = o["abc"] = 0
```

and the second step as doing assigments from right-to-left:

```
 (o["a"] = (o["ab"] = (o["abc"] = 0)))
 (o["a"] = (o["ab"] = 0))
 (o["a"] = 0)
```

I don't see how changing associativity for either step would change the performance. But if there is a reason, I would love to learn :)